# Unable to connect to network using terminal

Tags: networking, command-line, google-chrome

I have been trying to install programs using terminal but every time I get this error:

```
ccmb@ccmb-HP-Pro-3330-MT:~$ wget https://dl.google.com/linux/direct/google-chrome-stable_current_amd64.deb
--2015-02-17 21:48:07--  https://dl.google.com/linux/direct/google-chrome-stable_current_amd64.deb
Resolving dl.google.com (dl.google.com)... 173.194.126.7, 173.194.126.8, 173.194.126.9, ...
Connecting to dl.google.com (dl.google.com)|173.194.126.7|:443... failed: Connection refused.
Connecting to dl.google.com (dl.google.com)|173.194.126.8|:443... failed: Connection refused.
Connecting to dl.google.com (dl.google.com)|173.194.126.9|:443... failed: Connection refused.
Connecting to dl.google.com (dl.google.com)|173.194.126.14|:443... failed: Connection refused.
Connecting to dl.google.com (dl.google.com)|173.194.126.0|:443... failed: Connection refused.
Connecting to dl.google.com (dl.google.com)|173.194.126.1|:443... failed: Connection refused.
Connecting to dl.google.com (dl.google.com)|173.194.126.2|:443... failed: Connection refused.
Connecting to dl.google.com (dl.google.com)|173.194.126.3|:443... failed: Connection refused.
Connecting to dl.google.com (dl.google.com)|173.194.126.4|:443... failed: Connection refused.
Connecting to dl.google.com (dl.google.com)|173.194.126.5|:443... failed: Connection refused.
Connecting to dl.google.com (dl.google.com)|173.194.126.6|:443... failed: Connection refused.
Connecting to dl.google.com (dl.google.com)|2404:6800:4001:800::1003|:443... failed: Network is unreachable.
ccmb@ccmb-HP-Pro-3330-MT:~$
```

can anyone help me fix this

1. when using ping -c 4

   ```
   PING dl.l.google.com (74.125.130.91) 56(84) bytes of data.
   64 bytes from 74.125.130.91: icmp_seq=1 ttl=46 time=62.8 ms
   64 bytes from 74.125.130.91: icmp_seq=2 ttl=46 time=70.7 ms
   64 bytes from 74.125.130.91: icmp_seq=3 ttl=46 time=99.1 ms
   64 bytes from 74.125.130.91: icmp_seq=4 ttl=46 time=48.9 ms
   --- dl.l.google.com ping statistics ---
   4 packets transmitted, 4 received, 0% packet loss, time 3004ms
   rtt min/avg/max/mdev = 48.950/70.409/99.104/18.311 ms
   ```
2. using nslookup

   ```
   Server:     127.0.1.1
   Address:    127.0.1.1#53
   Non-authoritative answer:
   dl.google.com   canonical name = dl.l.google.com.
   Name:   dl.l.google.com
   Address: 74.125.130.93
   Name:   dl.l.google.com
   Address: 74.125.130.136
   Name:   dl.l.google.com
   Address: 74.125.130.190
   Name:   dl.l.google.com
   Address: 74.125.130.91
   ```
3. nslookup dl.google.com 8.8.8.8

   ```
   Server:     8.8.8.8
   Address:    8.8.8.8#53
   Non-authoritative answer:
   dl.google.com   canonical name = dl.l.google.com.
   Name:   dl.l.google.com
   Address: 74.125.236.192
   Name:   dl.l.google.com
   Address: 74.125.236.199
   Name:   dl.l.google.com
   Address: 74.125.236.196
   Name:   dl.l.google.com
   Address: 74.125.236.197
   Name:   dl.l.google.com
   Address: 74.125.236.198
   Name:   dl.l.google.com
   Address: 74.125.236.194
   Name:   dl.l.google.com
   Address: 74.125.236.200
   Name:   dl.l.google.com
   Address: 74.125.236.206
   Name:   dl.l.google.com
   Address: 74.125.236.201
   Name:   dl.l.google.com
   Address: 74.125.236.193
   Name:   dl.l.google.com
   Address: 74.125.236.195
   ```

Comment: The file is available to me via wget and firefox. Maybe you have a DNS problem. Try `ping -c 4 dl.google.com` and if it fails, try `nslookup dl.google.com` and if that also fails `nslookup dl.google.com 8.8.8.8` and post the outputs as edit to your question.

Comment: Are you behind a proxy, firewall, etc.?

Comment: yes yes iam using my work wifi

Comment: @VigneswaraPrabhu: I think this might be due to Google blocking your IP. Try via a proxy to be sure of it.

Comment: @heemayl or work WiFi blocking access to google. I would start by asking network admins at work for any log hits related to this, and work from there.

Answer (score 0):

As you're on a corporate LAN, please go talk to your IT department as they are actively blocking your requests, or just do this at home or in an Internet café...  **;-)**